# Apache vhost directory never used

Tags: debian, apache2, virtualhost

I’m setting a new server on Debian 9, but this time I’m struggling with the vhosts.

Basically, the vhosts never reach their DocumentRoot, but fallback on the default DocumentRoot (`/var/www/html`). As this is usually a simple matter of finding the right configuration, this time I don’t get it to work.

I reduced the conf files to the strict minimum to work on the problem. Let’s take 2 vhosts conf examples:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    ServerName www.site1.com
    ServerAlias www.site1.com
    ServerAdmin contact@test.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/site1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    ServerName www.site2.com
    ServerAlias www.site2.com
    ServerAdmin contact@test.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/site2
</VirtualHost>
```

In this case, going either on `www.site1.com` or `www.site2.com` will fall to the default page on `/var/www/html`.

If I’m changing one of the `120.0.0.1:80` to `*:80`, it is immediately set as the working vhost. But if I set both on `*:80`, it will fall on the first in the list.

Meaning if I have this:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    ServerName www.site1.com
    ServerAlias www.site1.com
    ServerAdmin contact@test.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/site1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.site2.com
    ServerAlias www.site2.com
    ServerAdmin contact@test.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/site2
</VirtualHost>
```

`www.site1.com` and `www.site2.com` will lead to `/var/www/site2`. Same the other way.

But if I do this :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.site1.com
    ServerAlias www.site1.com
    ServerAdmin contact@test.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/site1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.site2.com
    ServerAlias www.site2.com
    ServerAdmin contact@test.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/site2
</VirtualHost>
```

Then `www.site1.com` and `www.site2.com` will fall on `www.site1.com`.

I triple checked my `apache.conf`, `ports.conf`. They’re both on the default settings after a fresh install.

All the usual answers on "solved" similar posts have been tried and checked:
`apachectl -t` returns a `Syntax OK`.
All conf files end with `.conf`.
The chmod have been set to various tries, including 755, 775 and 777.
The matching user is set on the directories too.
I tried to sudo everything, restarting, reloading, etc.
I did reboot the server.
I’ve set the log on debug, but I can’f find everything wrong in it (though I’m not sure what to look for).

Just in case, here’s my `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   sd-*****.dedibox.fr sd-****
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts

::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

and hostname:

```
sd-*****
```

I really don’t know what’s going on now. Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, for some odd reasons I managed to get it to work with the second scheme, putting every vhost as `*:80`.

Although it works, I have no clue about why my usual settings didn't work this time, nor about what I did to get it to work…